# Unable to get TRACE output using Log4j even after adding the logger definition to log4j config file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, logging

I am unable to see 'Trace' output in Eclipse console using a maven project. Could somebody help me on this?   
Log4j Config File: **log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<configuration status="WARN">    
<appenders>    
  <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">    
   <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
  </Console>
</appenders>
<loggers>
 <logger name="p1.App" level="trace">
 <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
 </logger>
 <root level="error">  
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/> 
 </root>
</loggers> 
</configuration>
```

My Java class file: **App.java**

```
package p1;    
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class App {
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class.getName());
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    logger.error("Error");
    logger.trace("Trace");   
}
}
```

Before running I have set the classpath properly for log4j.xml. Please suggest me, what else I have to configure?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can somebody tell me any thing need to be added/edited in my log4j.xml file..?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  you are using log4j 1.2 (and not log4j2) the specifing the level is done using an element inside the logger element rather then an attribute on the logger element.

```
<logger name="p1.App">
   <level name="trace" />
   <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
 </logger>
```

Also make sure that your log4j.xml is inside the src/main/resources directory, it will not work when it is inside the src/main/java directory (it will be filtered as it isn't a java file).

Comment: Hi Deinum, I am using latest version of log4j 2.0(apache-log4j-2.0-beta8-bin.zip from [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html). I have included the required log4j 2.x jar files by adding dependencies in "pom.xml". Also as you said I have moved my log4j.xml to  "src/main/resources" directory, and set the classpath, but there is no progress.. :(

Comment: Any solution for this? Do I need to add anything to my "pom.xml"?

Comment: How have you added those to the pom? There are no 2.0 Log4J jars in the maven repository so if you haven't added them yourself to your local repo, maven isn't going to work for Log4J V2.

Comment: As mentioned in their site, I followed the steps given in the  link (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) added dependencies to the "pom.xml" and it downloaded the log4j 2.0 jars from maven repository.

Comment: If the log4j.xml is in the src/main/resource and that is added to the classpath (I suggest using the m2eclipse plugin which manages that for you, saves you some headache, or `mvn eclipse:eclipse` saves you from editing the classpath manually). Also according to [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) the file has to be named **log4j2.xml** and not log4j.xml